# Simple 3D Editor/Viewer

Tags: c#, graphics, editor, 3d

I'm looking for an application, which could be able to load bunch of points in space, render them and be able to simple 3D operations (select such point, rotate & move viewport).

The source has to be available, as I want to use it as basis for my own application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directX to solve this problem. I had done this using delphi and directX.
You can implement it using c# also.

**which could be able to load bunch of points in space**
You can do this by reading a textfile or binary file as you like and store it in buffer.

```
TD3DXVector3 temppt = D3DXVector3(X,Y,Z);
```

Here, TD3DXVector3 is type in directX.

**render them**
For rendering, there is a method *DrawPrimitive* of IDirect3DDevice9, using which you can render point, line or triangle.

```
g_pd3dDevice.DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST,0,count);
```

Here, Count is the number of triangles you want to draw.

**select such point, rotate & move viewport**
For rotation and moving viewport you can use transformation matrices for Projection transformation, View Transformation and world Transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Allegro library is easier to use except its only 2d, there might be a 3d interface to DirectX though. You need to know C++. Heres an initialization file for random pixels:

You can get the library from allegro.cc and use visual studio to compile it.

EDIT:
Heres an allegroGL example. Its allegro combined with openGL.
http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/589211

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "allegro.h"
int main()
{
    int x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2;
    int red, green, blue, color;

    allegro_init();

    install_keyboard();

    srand(time(NULL));

    int ret = set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640,480,0,0);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        allegro_message(allegro_error);
        return 0;
    }

//textprintf(screen, font, 0,0,15,"Pixels program - %dx%d - press esc to quit", SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H);

    while(!key[KEY_ESC])
    {
        x = 10+rand()%(SCREEN_W - 20);
        y = 10+rand()%(SCREEN_H - 20);

        red = rand() % 255;
        green = rand() % 255;
        blue = rand() % 255;
        color = makecol(red,green,blue);
        putpixel(screen,x,y,color);
      }
      allegro_exit();
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source 3D editors, but you'll find that most of them are associated with a particular 3D engine (i.e. irrEdit => Irrlicht).

There's Blender, but I suspect it's far too complex to find the code you want.

In a few minutes of Googling, I haven't been able to find a simple example of a 3D editor with source code included, but I have found this, which may be useful:

[Programming a 3D Editor](http://www.3dkingdoms.com/EditorTutorial.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There is http://Clara.io, the source isn't available but it is free and you can easily write plugins to import/export in a custom format and also add your own objects in the scene.